# Windows partitions have the same c: on disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, bcd

I have 2 windows 7 installed on two C: E partitions:

BCD menu is:

Windows7 1

Windows7 2

when I choose in any of the 2, I enter my pc, they have the same partition C:
and show the other partition with the letter E:

I remember installing windows7 2 on e:

why windows7 2 shows that it is in c: instead of e: someone explains to me?

Comment: `they have the same partition C:` and `windows7 2 shows that it is in c:` suggest that both systems exist on the same partition (they are the same system?). But it may be each one exists on its respective partition and only *names* it `C:`. In this case `C:` in one Windows is different than `C:` in the other. I would kinda expect this but `they have the same partition C:` doesn't correspond. Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the partition letter that Windows assigns to the system partition (i.e. the partition where it is booting from) is named the C partition. This explains why from the perspective of each Windows 7 deployment, it is installed on the C partition.

The partition names (in your case C and E) aren't unique. They are mnemonics to show the user which partition is which. Each Windows installation chooses how to call these partitions (and ou can change it in the disk manager if you want). In the background, every partition has a unique ID (that is globally unique, and therefore is called the **G**lobal **U**nique **ID**entifier.
This is how Windows can differentiate between both partitions, since the way they see it is the same for every deployment.

What is actually happening is the following:

The perspective of Windows 7 (1):

- Partition With Windows 7 (1): GUID = 00000000-0000-0000-000000000001 and Partition name = C:
- Partition With Windows 7 (2): GUID = 00000000-0000-0000-000000000002 and Partition name = E:

The perspective of Windows 7 (2):

- Partition With Windows 7 (1): GUID = 00000000-0000-0000-000000000001 and Partition name = E:
- Partition With Windows 7 (2): GUID = 00000000-0000-0000-000000000002 and Partition name = C:

TL;DR: What you are seeing makes sense.